# How does ubuntu 18.04 (gnome) autodetect monitor changes?

Tags: gnome, xorg, monitor, xrandr, udev

In Ubuntu 18.04, when I dock my laptop, the monitor layout gets assigned to the previous configuration I had when the laptop was undocked.

Recently I changed distro & desktop environment and I want to replicate this on my new setup.

I learned about [autorandr](https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr) but after searching my old system I found out that it was not installed there.

So, which part of GNOME/ubuntu configuration handles this change? Is it baked inside the code somewhere or can it be extracted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
this is actually done by gnome, there's more to it than just this but this is what determines default monitor setup.
org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr/default-monitors-setup (recently moved to [mutter](https://gitlab.gnome.org/denittis/gnome-settings-daemon/-/commit/cbf313e689f5853b85c6f7c08ac233688408c8e8)).
If this doesn't' work for you, you can try finding where what you're looking for is by setting up alerts when you plugin monitors

[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13746/how-can-i-detect-when-a-monitor-is-plugged-in-or-unplugged)
and check and see what gnome settings were altered or accessed when you plugin a monitor.

ORIGINAL:
gnome tweaks has a tool for this
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1066/fix-multi-monitors/

to install gnome tweaks (which comes with all sorts of nifty extensions and lots of settings) Open up terminal and type

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

you can then go to applications and open tweaks, turn on extensions. Then go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1066/fix-multi-monitors/
there should be a switch at the top that you can switch that will turn it on and you're all set!

This works for me even when I disconnect from a dock or monitor then add it back it automatically remembers their location relative to each other!

Comment: Thanks, my question is not about how I can do it in ubuntu/gnome (since it works out of the box) but what kind of system does ubuntu use to achieve this goal.

Comment: @orestisf so this is actually done by gnome, there's more to it than just this but this is what determines default monitor setup. 
org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/xrandr/default-monitors-setup

Comment: @orestisf If this doesn't' work for you, you can try finding where what you're looking for is by setting up alerts when you plugin monitors [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13746/how-can-i-detect-when-a-monitor-is-plugged-in-or-unplugged) and check and see what gnome settings were altered or accessed when you plugin a monitor.

Comment: Thank you. Do you want to edit your answer or add a new answer so that I can accept it? The functionality was moved to mutter recently btw: https://gitlab.gnome.org/denittis/gnome-settings-daemon/-/commit/cbf313e689f5853b85c6f7c08ac233688408c8e8

Comment: @orestisf I'll edit my answer, thank you so much!